# How to change the text colour of a date in CalenderView in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

how do you change the text colour of a date in a CalendarView in android? Specifically I want to know how to achieve this programmatically as all the examples I've seen so far are based on XML but I would like to achieve this dynamically. For example I am using a database which has a date and field that indicates true or false. When it's true I want the text colour of that date to be different.

Below is the example I found in XML: https://kotlin-android.com/android-calendarview-tutorial-kotlin/.

I assumed I can just update the `dateTextAppearance` attribute for CalendarView but I don't think I can assign a value to it.

```
var calendarActivity: CalendarView = findViewById(R.id.next_month_calendar_view)
println(calendarActivity.dateTextAppearance)
```

The print statement gets me `16974789`, throwing the number into an int to colour converter gets me a bright pinkish colour but the calendar view doesn't have that colour.

So my question is how do you change the text colour of a given date in kotlin programmitically for a CalendarView?

Comment: Share the code where you set color programmitically

Comment: There isn't one because I don't even know what attribute can be changed to set a particular date's colour

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/CleverPumpkin/CrunchyCalendar) it's fully customizable and has better material design

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. I hope they add more custom functionality to the calendarview or the material design calenderview. I think a lot of people will appreciate the ability to make modifications to the calendar